# Come Sail Away - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Crazy or not, you know who I am,
I can use a knife, not just for jam.
Death is nothing new to me.
You know the glasses that help me see.
Rogue or not, I've saved the world.
I salute when the flag is unfurled.
The future I thought I once knew,
Instead honesty became my main view.
Is it day or night, light or dark,
Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

Hint 1:

> The title contains a clue as well.

Hint 2:

> 4, 6, and 10 are related.

Hint 3:

> The answer is a specific person.

Comment: Are you Styx? :)

Comment: the band Knife Party?

Comment: Is the capitalization of Jam intentional?

Comment: Nope. Must have accidentally hit shift.

Comment: Crazy or not, shine on you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I think I got it this time.  The answer is:

> Tom Cruise

Come Sail Away

> Cruise = sailing away

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> Some say he's crazy for being a Scientologist, but he's world famous

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> Mission Impossible "knife in the eye" stunt among other fight scenes

Death is nothing new to me.

> Interview With A Vampire, or the death count in his action movies

You know the glasses that help me see.

> The aviator glasses he wore in Top Gun

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> Mission Impossible: he became a rogue agent once but he saved the world

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> Top Gun or Born on the Fourth of July (according to hint, Top Gun)

The future I thought I once knew,

> Minority Report (precognition) or Edge of Tomorrow (reliving the same day)

Instead honesty became my main view.

> A Few Good Men ("I want the truth!" "You can't handle the truth!")

Is it day or night, light or dark,

> Knight and Day movie

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> F-14 from Top Gun

Comment: That's a good one

Comment: +1 I really feel like this is the right answer. I've been thinking this for a while but for the life of me I couldn't connect it with the title.

Comment: Perfect! I was also linking Edge of To or row with the death line. Nicely done!

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's right because some clues feel forced, but others feel solid so I'll post anyway... You are:

> The moon

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> "Crazy or not" refers to superstitions, werewolves and such.

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> Crescent moon looks like a knife.

Death is nothing new to me.

> The moon holds no life.

You know the glasses that help me see.

> ...um, yeah... Reference to craters making up the eyes of the man in the moon? Reference to the "oo" in the middle of moon that look like glasses on the word itself?

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> It's thought that the moon was created by a collision with earth by another "rogue" solar system body ("or not" because it's not certain), and now protects us from other meteor collisions.

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> Reference to the moon landing?

The future I thought I once knew,
Instead honesty became my main view.

> The moon was used in astrology for predicting the future, now we're more scientific and honest about its nature.

Is it day or night, light or dark,

> Has dark and light sides, thus day and night are ambiguous, plus we see it during the day and at night.

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> The moon still has moon buggies parked on it, which is very cool. :)

Comment: +1 for sure. Not what I was going for, but I like the applications.

Answer (score 3):

and I guess the anwer is

> Batman

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> Fans or otherwise, we all have heard of him.

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> Bat-Sword or the pneumatic mangler or the batarang.

Death is nothing new to me.

> For he strives to keep the world safe and defy death.

You know the glasses that help me see.

> Cowl Lenses

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> He sure does

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> Patriotic as he is.

The future I thought I once knew,

Instead honesty became my main view.
Is it day or night, light or dark,

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> BatMobile Bike

Need to add more logic to the explanation.

Comment: I like it, but not quite. I'd say Batman works at night and in the dark, but definitely +1.

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't really fit with the title hint, but maybe I'm just missing the connection? Either way, worth a shot...

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> Anakin Skywalker

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> A lightsaber

Death is nothing new to me.

> He has killed many, and Obi-Wan says Darth Vader killed him

You know the glasses that help me see.

> The Vader helmet

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> Anything from the battle of Naboo in I to the death of the Emperor in VI
>
>  Rogue refers to being a rogue jedi, and/or becoming a sith

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> He's on the side of the Empire

The future I thought I once knew,

> Had premonition dreams

Instead honesty became my main view.

> "I am your father"?

Is it day or night, light or dark,

> Time of day in space is ambiguous at best
>
>  Light and dark side of the Force

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> Darth Vader and his TIE/x1... or Star Destroyer... or Death Star...

Comment: +1 for the attempt for sure. I really like it. Not it though. Personally, I wouldn't consider a lightsaber a knife, but maybe that is just me.

Comment: I was thinking it might be artistic license ;)

Answer (score 3):

This might not be right, but I think it could be close. Are you:

> A pirate (More so, Jack sparrow from The Pirates of the Caribbean)

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> Most people know about pirates

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> They often use knives and swords as weapons while fighting

Death is nothing new to me.

> Pirates are often in fights to the death with others

You know the glasses that help me see.

> Possibly referring to a spy glass which helps them see longer distances on sea

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> Jack has fought against Davy Jones and Hector Barbossa to protect the world!

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> He will salute his flag and also a possible reference to honoring the pirate code.

The future I thought I once knew,

> Jack thought he was always an evil pirate

Instead honesty became my main view.

> After meeting with Will Turner and Elizabeth Swann his views change to a becoming a better more honest pirate (for as far as pirating can go)

Is it day or night, light or dark,

> This could reference being inside a boat you can't tell the time of day. Also a possible small reference to the use of an eye patch which helps in literal light and dark situations.

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> Jack Sparrow, and his ship the Black Perl!

Also the title "Come sail away"

> A reference to him and his crew to sail away in his ship.

Comment: +1 I like it . Very nice, but not the answer. You make these fit very well though. I will say the glasses refered to are actual glasses, just a specific type.

Answer (score 2):

Partial Answer:

You are:

> Charon, the Boatman

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

I can use a knife, not just for Jam.

> He uses the staff to guide his way down the River Styx (Title reference)

Death is nothing new to me.

You know the glasses that help me see.

> The River Styx takes the newly deceased to the underworld.

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> Charon the boatman. He parks his awesome boat on the riverbank

Comment: Not what I was thinking of, but I'll definately give a vote up if you can make it match all of the clues.

Comment: That's why it's a partial, I can't :) But I'll try now!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're

> a wave

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> Everybody knows what a wave is

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> There is a type of knife that has a waved shaped blade

Death is nothing new to me.

> Many sailors died because of waves

You know the glasses that help me see.

> I don't know for that one. The only thing I can think of is a word play between *see* and *sea*. I'll put that on the fact that English is my second language ^^

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> I am not sure of this one, I am thinking of the Deluge and Noah and his ark

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> Usually when the flag is unfurled, it's because of the wind. Which creates waves

The future I thought I once knew,
Instead honesty became my main view.

> I think those are working together because when there is no wave, you can see far away, but when there is big waves, that's the only thing you can see.

Is it day or night, light or dark,

> Waves are there no matter what day, what time of the day, what season

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> You are a wave and you park the surfers about to ride you. Surfers are cool :)

Comment: +1 Great attempt, but no. The title does indicate the type of answer.

Answer (score 1):

Crazy or not, you know who I am,

> The Nazi in Raiders of The Lost Ark

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> I think there was a scene in the movie

Death is nothing new to me.

> He's a Nazi

You know the glasses that help me see.

> He wears glasses and they are distinctive

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> ? Ok this doesn't fit

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> Obviously the Nazi flag

The future I thought I once knew,
Instead honesty became my main view.

> Vengeance from the Ark

Is it day or night, light or dark,
Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park

> Major Arnold Ernst Toht was driven in an open classic

Answer (score 1):

My guess:

> Captain America

Come sail away with me

> Captain = commander of a ship

Crazy or not, you know who I am

> Everyone has seen the movies

I can use a knife, not just for jam.

> Knife fight scene with Cap and Bucky in Winter Soldier.

Death is nothing new to me.

> Captain America died in the ice but was brought back to life.

You know the glasses that help me see.

> When Cap is in disguise in Winter Soldier, he wore glasses.

Rogue or not, I've saved the world.

> There is a comic called Captain America Rogues Gallery, and he has saved the world many times in the comics.

I salute when the flag is unfurled.

> Captain America is very patriotic.

The future I thought I once knew,

> He was born a long time ago but was frozen in ice and revived in the future.

Instead honesty became my main view.

> He is a paragon of honesty and virtue.

Is it day or night, light or dark

> Maybe referring to the band "Dark Captain Light Captain"?

Tell me who I am, and something cool that I park.

> Either the Chevrolet Corvette Stingray driven by Black Widow that Cap rode in, or maybe Red Skull's V16 Coupe?

Comment: Definitely a good approach, but not quite. The glasses referred to are well known, and highly associated with the answer.