# Still going strong - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

Search, searching, still searching am I,
For those that on that one day did die.
We don't even know the name of the place,
I'm going there, even if you can't keep pace.

In the world out there, some things are pure,
No flowers or vines, but named for sure.
I took it apart, and saved so many lives,
In the fight that left so many husbandless wives.

Most really like me, except when I was given.
Still trying to decide if I've been forgiven.
There was a close call, but it is alright,
Though for a while, I was quite the sight.

Hint 1:

> For some direction on how the clues might be organized, see some of my other riddles, such as [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15731/you-may-know-me-who-am-i), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/alive-dead-alive-now-dead), or [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/come-sail-away-who-am-i).

Hint 2:

> Each stanza deals with something different.

Hint 3:

> "Who" may imply a singular that isn't singular.

Comment: 'I took it apart, and saved so many lives in the fight that left so many husbandless wive' <- all you're saving are widows?

Comment: @Alex If order matters, then yes. If it doesn't, then not really.

Comment: To me, this sounds like references to the atomic bomb and the end of WWII.  I'm not sure "who" is being referred to, though.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain You are on for a portion. Let me post a hint that I think will help.

Comment: Hint2: Armstrong?

Comment: @Alex Nope, not Armstrong.

Comment: Is the title correct? "STILL GOING strong"? If so, the person must be alive then...

Comment: Is second stanza about a person who broke some kind of code? Enigma maybe? World with 'pure names' but without living beings that will save lives.. cryptography?

Comment: @MarekOleszczuk No code, and the answer is definately still alive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you are

> U2 or Bono

Part one refers to songs:

Search, searching, still searching am I,

> Still havent found what i am looking for

For those that on that one day did die.

> Bloody Sunday

We don't even know the name of the place,

> Where the Streets have no name

I'm going there, even if you can't keep pace.

> With our without you?

Thx to Player one:

part 2 refer to Album titles

In the world out there, some things are pure,
No flowers or vines, but named for sure.
I took it apart, and saved so many lives,
In the fight that left so many husbandless wives.

> Songs of Innocence, The Joshua Tree, How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb, War

thx to aioros:

part 3 seems to refer to their persona

Most really like me, except when I was given.

> I tune fiasco when record was given for free

Still trying to decide if I've been forgiven.

could also refer to this.

More thoughts:

close call could refer to a nearly plane crash they had some time ago...

Comment: You know what, this sounds a little silly but it actually makes sense. I'm going to add "How to dismantle an atomic bomb" at least. Oh, and "Most really like me except when I was given" could be that iTunes fiasco.

Comment: You've got the main answer. See if you can fit the rest of the clues in now. Know that each stanza deals with a different "topic" and you have fulfilled the first.

Comment: The second stanza is U2 album names - in order: Songs of Innocence, The Joshua Tree, How to Dismantle an Atomic Bomb, War

Comment: Very nice. The last couple of lines I was thinking of Bono's recent bike crash, but the plane crash works too.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it is

> COMET

Search, searching, still searching am I,

> Some Comets keep going forever (in an orbit) unknown to us what they are after.

For those that on that one day did die.

> Looking for stars that perished or are blown away from wherein they are born

We don't even know the name of the place,

> Not every place in the Universe has been named yet.

I'm going there, even if you can't keep pace.

> Humans on earth have not yet figured out how to outpace a Comet

In the world out there, some things are pure,

> Pure like a single element

No flowers or vines, but named for sure.

> Some comets have names like Halley or Hyakutake

I took it apart, and saved so many lives,

> Comets could have crashed into Asteroids implying they saved lives on Spaceships which could have run into those.

In the fight that left so many husbandless wives.

> Some war during planet sightings coz in earlier days wars were fought with mostly men, unlike online cyber wars of today with no men ;-).

Most really like me, except when I was given.

> It is a play on the word COMETH opposite of GIVETH.

Still trying to decide if I've been forgiven.
There was a close call, but it is alright,

Though for a while, I was quite the sight.

> Comets look different than other visible planetary bodies in the sky and are quite a sight.

Comment: +1 Some good thoughts, but no. The question is "Who am I"

Comment: @AggieKidd you mean it is a personality to be identified? a character from a famous book/teleserial.

Comment: the answer can be classified as "who". Can't say too much more than that yet.

Answer (score 2):

Am sure this isn't the answer but a try nonetheless:

> is it a MINE

Search, searching, still searching am I,
For those that on that one day did die.
We don't even know the name of the place,
I'm going there, even if you can't keep pace.

> a mine is hidden (place name not known) and it searches for the person who it can kill

I took it apart, and saved so many lives,
In the fight that left so many husbandless wives.

> Mines stop the enemy and save lives on one side but also leave dead on another side

This is the most sense i could derive. Not sure about the last stanza

Comment: Nope, not a mine. Good try though.

Answer (score 2):

I think I can take a crack at it. Although I haven't been able to find something suiting each verse.

> Is it Morgan Freeman?

Still going strong

> Freeman is 78 but still continues to make a number of movies.

Search, searching, still searching am I,
For those that on that one day did die.

> Reference to the movie Se7en, where he plays a detective tracking a serial killer.

We don't even know the name of the place,
I'm going there, even if you can't keep pace.

> Shawshank Redemption, because he joins his prison mate Tim Robbins at the end of the movie at an unknown place.

In the world out there, some things are pure,
No flowers or vines, but named for sure.

> Not sure about this one...

I took it apart, and saved so many lives,
In the fight that left so many husbandless wives.

> Morgan Freeman played Nelson Mandela in Invictus where he took apart the system of apartheid and saved many lives.

Most really like me, except when I was given.
Still trying to decide if I've been forgiven.

> Reference to the movie Unforgiven?

There was a close call, but it is alright,
Though for a while, I was quite the sight.

> Could refer to his accident in 2008, whose pictures became quite viral at the time.

Comment: +1 Very nice effort, but no. Each line is a separate clue. There are sections of the lines that are important (day, you keeping pace)

Comment: @AggieKidd: Have I got any of the references right, even if it's not Freeeman?

Comment: The one about the title is kind of on the right track.

Answer (score 2):

I have a guess. It's my first one about this puzzle, but I want to try - the answer is:

> MEMORY

Let's see:

Search, searching, still searching am I,
For those that on that one day did die.
We don't even know the name of the place,
I'm going there, even if you can't keep pace.

> Memory is always searching for something, sometimes we want to recall a person, a date, sometimes about our relative's. As for the place - we can't say where our thoughts are located. We point on our brain, but we feel otherwise.

In the world out there, some things are pure,
No flowers or vines, but named for sure.
I took it apart, and saved so many lives,
In the fight that left so many husbandless wives.

> In our memory, we keep ideal images/names of various things. We try to keep our relatives' names. Soldiers who are wounded in a fight try to stick to thoughts about his/her wife and kids, and that for sure can save their lives in treatment.

Most really like me, except when I was given.
Still trying to decide if I've been forgiven.
There was a close call, but it is alright,
Though for a while, I was quite the sight.

> We like our memory, except for the time when we are forced to recall something. During tortures, prisoners are forced to recall something they want not to reveal. About last 2 werses - I'm not sure (I lack language skill I guess...).

Comment: I like your answer.

Comment: I like the answer, but it doesn't quite fit. Remember the question is asking for a "who"