# What is the plan - Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge

My legend will be remembered,
Too strong to be dismembered.
No happiness at the parting,
What happened at the starting?

All the lines or all we do,
Mix God, religion, and the facts too.
Counting now, what are we at?
Profound, noises, or like a cat?

My land is one full of life,
You know my cousins, little strife.
Started with two, but grew to three,
But with some help, who can I be?

Hint 1:

> Each line references something different.

Hint 2:

> Is a very similar format to another one of my recent riddles.

Hint 3:

> Thinking of the comment on [Marek's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/18181/9951), it might be more accurate to say *normal* human beings can be dismembered (but remember hint 1).

Hint 4:

> Check [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/alive-dead-alive-now-dead), [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17155/still-going-strong-who-am-i), [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15731/you-may-know-me-who-am-i), or [this riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12543/come-sail-away-who-am-i) for some similar formats.

Hint 5:

> What color do we often associate with life? What land/country is often associated with that color?

Hint 6:

> The answer is not an actor.

Comment: Is this of a similar format as http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16686/alive-dead-alive-now-dead ?

Comment: @CodeNewbie Perhaps. I will say it is very similar to at least one of my former puzzles.

Comment: Time for a hint?

Comment: @dennisdeems Yep!

Comment: Ok, Will Smith? ;)

Comment: @MarekOleszczuk Not Will Smith, but I'd be interested to see how you relate him to the clues.

Comment: Hm, there are several Actors for which i can connect some lines, but always only 3-4, not enough to make a guess... Will Smith was also on my list, because some of his movie titels could match some lines

Comment: @kl78 If you have issues with actors, maybe that is a hint.

Comment: Wish I read the comments before also trying to shoehorn Will Smith in there :).  I am Legend and Legend of Bagger Vance fit line 1, Hancock and I Robot fits line 2 (in the latter he lost his arm but then gained an artificial unbreakable replacement), There were 2 MiB, then they made a 3rd.  The Earth in After Earth had teemed with life.

Comment: Ireland? (hint #5)

Comment: @Spacemonkey Perhaps, but it would seem to fit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it:

> The Script (band)

Because:

> The second paragraph, each line references one of their albums:
>  *All the lines or all we do,* = **The Script**
>  *Mix God, religion, and the facts too.* = **Science & Faith**
>  *Counting now, what are we at?* = **#3**
>  *Profound, noises, or like a cat?* = **No Sound Without Silence**

And Also:

> **They are Irish**
>  *My land is one full of life,* **Ireland**
>  *You know my cousins, little strife.* **Northern Ireland**
>  *Started with two, but grew to three,* **They started as a band of two**

And I'm guessing that:

> **Each line of the first paragraph references one of their songs?**
>  *My legend will be remembered,* = **Hall of Fame**
>  *Too strong to be dismembered.* = **The Man Who Can't Be Moved**
>  *No happiness at the parting,* = **Six Degrees of Separation**
>  *What happened at the starting?* **For the First Time**

Comment: You got it! I'll award the bounty when I get to a computer. As a note, Too Strong I intended to be Superheros, but yours works as well!

Comment: @AggieKidd I did wonder if Superheroes was one of them, either first or second. But I decided Hall of Fame was more likely the first, and that all superheroes have a weakness so it can't be the second ;)

Answer (score 6):

Could you be

> An idea

My legend will be remembered,

> People remember idea's and they can given to others or created into a tangible object to continue existence.

Too strong to be dismembered.

> An idea can not be destroyed. It can be considered one of the most powerful things for humans.

No happiness at the parting,

> When an idea is given up on there could be no happiness.

What happened at the starting?

> Scientists don't understand how idea's are created, and some people often wonder where idea's originated from.

All the lines or all we do,

> All the lines of text, or all things we do are related to an idea. (i.e items we used were created from an idea, things we want to do are just initial idea's)

Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> A story can be about gods, religion, and science. More particularly the information/meaning behind the story.

Counting now, what are we at?

> A lot. There are a lot of idea's out there.

Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> possible reference to profound ideas, musical ideas (songs), and the internet....whose idea what it to put cats all over it!

My land is one full of life,

> Idea's come from imagination and nature, which is full of life (you are alive to think right?)

You know my cousins, little strife.

> Possible reference to conspiracies? People can get angry or bitter over them.

Started with two, but grew to three,

> Possible reference to the forms of sharing an idea. (Verbal, written, visual)

But with some help, who can I be?

> I think I might have just the *idea* of who you are.

Comment: I also just noticed today's google page is about a journalist. One who helps spread idea's (The possible seed of this riddle/answer).

Comment: +1 I like it, but no. The title is a key component as well, especially the question "Who" am I.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is

> Hades/Pluto? At first I thought the "planet", but I'm leaning more towards the god.

My legend will be remembered, 
Too strong to be dismembered.

> Mythology has stood the test of time and I expect it will keep on doing so, and Gods in myth can't really be killed by dismemberment, I don't believe.

No happiness at the parting,
What happened at the starting?

> Maybe refers to Persephone's abduction, and the sadness that comes with Fall and Winter.

All the lines or all we do,
Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> This may be referring to our thoughts on the afterlife.

Counting now, what are we at?
Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> Another reference to the afterlife? Like a cat, how many lives have we lived?

My land is one full of life,
You know my cousins, little strife.

> The underworld is full of lives/souls.
>  Strife (Eris) was known as two different entities.

Started with two, but grew to three,
But with some help, who can I be?

> Zeus and Poseidon were the two, Hades making three in the division of power over the world.

Comment: +1 Some good thoughts, but I wouldn't consider the underworld full of life.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> [the band Nirvana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_%28band%29)

My legend will be remembered, Too strong to be dismembered.

> Wikipedia says, "Despite releasing only three full-length studio albums in their seven-year career, Nirvana has come to be regarded as one of the most influential and important rock bands of the modern era."

No happiness at the parting, What happened at the starting?

> After lead singer [Kurt Cobain's death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Kurt_Cobain), the band came to an end, and the many fans were more than sad.

All the lines or all we do, Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> Many lines in many of Nirvana's songs referred to or alluded to God and/or religion. I can list examples if needed.

Counting now, what are we at? Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> I'm not sure. Maybe counting the days since Cobain's death? Also, could these three things reference songs or specific lyrics of the band?

My land is one full of life, You know my cousins, little strife.

> [The word Nirvana](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20nirvana&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) refers to "a transcendent state in which there is neither suffering, desire, nor sense of self" and "a state of perfect happiness" and "an ideal place". The "cousins" of Nirvana are places like heaven, paradise, Eden, the promised land, Shangri-La, or maybe even Valhalla

Started with two, but grew to three, But with some help, who can I be?

> The band was formed by just 2 guys: "singer and guitarist Kurt Cobain and bassist Krist Novoselic in Aberdeen, Washington, in 1987." The third member was added later (the drummer), which changed many times throughout the years.

Comment: +1 Definately a great attempt, but no. Each line is it's own clue.

Answer (score 3):

I may sound naive, but my answer is:

> human being

My legend will be remembered,

> human history will always be remembered

Too strong to be dismembered.

> people strive to not to be dismembered (everyone else needs some attention, some folks wanna be famous)

No happiness at the parting,

> when someone dies, other are mourning

What happened at the starting?

> how humanity began? it's one of the most fundamental questions

All the lines or all we do,

> culture of humanity is a sign of presence, we are what we produce with culture (broadly taken)

Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> human beginnings, also what people are talking/up to includes all ideas, including faith, religion, historical/science breakthroughs

Counting now, what are we at?

> (either:) it's hard to follow all humans' thoughts/trends/intentions
>  (or#1:) we can't really say what our future is or where we are getting to
>  (or#2:) we can't say when we die (we can't tell how long we will live from now

Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> (no idea yet, still working on it...)

My land is one full of life,

> humans live on Earth, which is 'full of life' (we can't, at least, for now, live in a place without organic life or other ecosystem)

You know my cousins, little strife.

> (either:) humans don't really always get along with other humans...
>  (or:) monkeys? animals? not really a threat, but still

Started with two, but grew to three,

> humanity needs male+female to reproduce, a child is 'three' then (not really male or female in terms of reproducing till maturity)

But with some help, who can I be?

> with help of genetic engineering?

Comment: A good attempt, but no. Humans try not to be dismembered, but they can be. I will use your answer in a hint later.

Answer (score 3):

I have a suggestion as to what it is. There are a couple of lines in particular that scream that this is what it is, but I can't fit some of the more "ambiguous" lines in. Is it:

> Israel/The Jews?

My legend will be remembered,

> The story of Israel's survival is legendary

Too strong to be dismembered.

> The Jews survived the holocaust, 'nuff said.

No happiness at the parting,

> In biblical times, Judah split off from Israel

What happened at the starting?

> Unsure, but the history of the Jews does go back like, 4000 years.

All the lines or all we do,

> Unsure

Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> Speaks for itself really

Counting now, what are we at?

> King David counted the Israelites in 1 Chronicles 21, if you carried on counting, the numbers would be ridiculous.

Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> Unsure

My land is one full of life,

> God gave them the land of Israel and it "flowed with milk and honey"

You know my cousins, little strife.

> The Arab nations come from the line of Esau, which was the brother of Jacob, the father of Israel. Obviously we know the strife between Israel and the Arab nations.

Started with two, but grew to three,

> Unsure, but perhaps a reference to WWII where America joined the fight later on. (Reference to fighting the Holocaust?)

But with some help, who can I be?

> Israel have had lots of financial help from America

Comment: Definitely a good attempt and what you have fits pretty wells, but those that you are missing make the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, this is my guess.

You are:

> Dr Robert Neville - I Am Legend

And your plan is:

> To find a cure to the zombie virus.

My legend will be remembered,

> Dr Neville was the legend, surviving the virus and trying to cure it.

Too strong to be dismembered.

> Dismembering is a classic in zombie films/books, but he was too strong to die to the outbreak.

No happiness at the parting,

> When parting with his family, when they died.. there was no happiness. Or when his dog, Sam dies. Parting is never happy.

What happened at the starting?

> The big question, how did this outbreak start?

All the lines or all we do,

> This one, I'm unsure about

Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> God, religion.. everything is being questioned when a thing only seen in Sci-Fi films becomes real.

Counting now, what are we at?

> How many days has he survived? How many zombies are there? Counting the days that go by.

Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> Moaning of zombies, and other scary things.

My land is one full of life,

> Either a sarcastic statement, or an optimistic one. Zombies, while alive.. are not really alive.

You know my cousins, little strife.

> His family, all dead? When you're family is dead there isn't much to argue about with them.

Started with two, but grew to three,

> Zombies, they multiply! Two become three, three become six.. etc

But with some help, who can I be?

> He can be the legend he needs to be with the help of the children.. who looked after the cure after he killed himself to save the rest of humanity. And after he died, he is the martyr.. the legend that saved humanity.

Comment: Nice effort, but no. Check some of the hints to help narrow down the options. The full of life does mean full of life. Plus, I sure hope zombies don't make profound noises.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is

> Deadpool & Cable (they share dna)

My legend will be remembered,

> These seem to fit both: Both are character cards in the Marvel Legendary Card Game

Too strong to be dismembered.

> Deadpool regrows from his head being smashed in by the Hulk and reattaches limbs, including head, a few other times - this is either because of his healing factor or because Thanos cursed him with immortality. Cable is restored using bionic technology and other means.

No happiness at the parting,

> Again with Thanos, DeadPool fell in love with/was loved by death so Thanos cursed him with life so they could never meet. The Summer’s family tree is one of painful partings.

What happened at the starting?

> DeadPool repeatedly lies about his origins and is not even sure about them himself - not even sure he is Wade Wilson. Cable started out with no explanation of where he came from or who he was and this was only gradually expanded over the years.

All the lines or all we do,

> These seem to fit Deadpool: All Deadpool/Cable comics are famous for breaking the fourth wall

Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> Anything and everything can come out of Deadpool’s mouth

Counting now, what are we at?

> Deadpool has “died” several times in the comics (in fact he’s currently dead).

Profound, noises, or like a cat?

> On rare occasion Deadpool does something profound or heroic, the rest is noise - and his ideal mercenary is “the cat”

My land is one full of life,

> These seem to fit Cable. Cable’s Providence is meant to preserve life into the future (prevent the apocalyptic future he came from)

You know my cousins, little strife.

> Cable’s clone is Stryfe, his uncles: Havok and Vulcan

Started with two, but grew to three,

> Cable and Nathan Summers were shown early with his clone Stryfe coming later

But with some help, who can I be?

> Nathan Summers will someday grow into Cable but (due to the changes possible in time travel) he may not.

For Hints #3 and #6

> “normal human beings” and *not an actor*

And #5

> Green is the color I’m guessing (could be red or blue though) and parts of Providence are found in the Verde Base.

Comment: Some are a little bit of a stretch, but they fit better than any thus far +1. Not quite though.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to find a proper link but I'm pretty sure its something like:

> A list of Brad Pitt movies

My legend will be remembered,

> Legends of the Fall

Too strong to be dismembered.

> Troy

No happiness at the parting,

> Meet Joe Black

What happened at the starting?

> Fight Club

All the lines or all we do,
Mix God, religion, and the facts too.

> 

Counting now, what are we at?

> Se7en

Profound, noises, or like a cat?

My land is one full of life,

> Snatch (as per Hint #5)

You know my cousins, little strife.

Started with two, but grew to three,

> Could be the Ocean's 11 movies, I think it's the only trilogy he's been in...

But with some help, who can I be?

Comment: A good theory, but no. I am serious when I ask "Who am I?"

Comment: you could be an oscar or an award or something! - but ok, i'll dig my brain some more - in line with movies still, Brad Pitt would fit a bunch, Legends of the Fall, Troy, Se7en, Fight Club (what happened at the starting), etc...